# How to inject data into graphql file in karate

Tags: graphql, automated-tests, karate

I am using [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) for my GraphQL tests. (Ideally, I would like to use [JavaFaker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) to create data for the create statements).

Is there a way to do this?